# How to prevent corruption from ruining synced backups

Tags: backup, keepass, availability, dropbox

I thought I was being clever keeping my password database stored on dropbox. This is because it's synced to the cloud and multiple computers. But when one got corrupted, I lost everything. (Ok I exaggerate, [I got it back](https://superuser.com/questions/1159090/keepass-password-safe-corrupt?noredirect=1#comment1669550_1159090), but if I wasn't lucky I may not have.)

How can such situations be guarded against where a) corrupted data is backed up and the old backup was disposed of or b) the backup process itself somehow corrupts the target. I guess in corporate environments that can support it, this is why they store more than just the most recent backups.

What is a practical solution for a home user to backup a frequently modified password database?

By the way, my hunch is dropbox was responsible for the corruption in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a private Git repository - automate the push every night. If you want, you can even host this repo on a private server to ensure that no one else has access to it. Or save the KeePass DB to a veracrypt file and encrypt that file before pushing.

Answer (score 0):

A backup cannot be a simple copy, because you absolutely must keep different versions. If you do not you will only mitigate the risk of disk failure, but not the risk of inadvertant file modification.

Fortunately, you can find free backup utilities like the excellent [Cobian backup](http://www.cobiansoft.com/cobianbackup), that can be configured like what you call *corporate environment*, for example a full backup every month (you can even keep several of them) an incremental based on last full one every week, and a differential every day. It does require a bit of initial config, but it does works it.